# Programming a delay in Matlab

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, digital-communications, delay

Let $x(t)$ a signal of duration $T$, the sampling frequency is $f_s$.
I  know the signal $x(t+\tau)$ orresponds to a signal delayed by a delay $\tau$. In Matlab, the signal $x(t+\tau)$ is given by: $[0,...,0,x(1),...,x(N)]$ where $\texttt{size}([0,...,0],2)=\tau f_s$ and $\texttt{size}([x(1),...,x(N)],2)=Tf_s$.

My problem is that I don't see how to code the signal $x(\tau-t)$ with Matlab. However, I noticed that $x(\tau-t)=x(-(t-\tau))$ so I think you need to use matlab's `fliplr` command. Is that correct?

Comment: I believe this question is better suited for StackOverflow since it is a programming question. There is some relevance to Signal Processing since it is about delaying a signal but I do believe it is more appropriate to be migrated to StackOverflow.

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

1. > In Matlab, the signal $x(t+\tau)$ is given by: $[0,...,0,x(1),...,x(N)]$.

   **No, that's $x(t-\tau)$.**

   $x(t+\tau)$ is a forward delay, so it's actually $[x(\tau
   f_s),...,x(N)]$
2. Yes, $x(\tau - t) = x(-(t-\tau))$ which in Matlab can be computed with `fliplr` (or `flipud`)

*Note: If you want the delayed signal $x(t-\tau)$ to be the same length as the original, it's $[0,...,0,x(1),...,x(N-\tau f_s + 1)]$*.